# How can I hide a column in a Kendo Grid based on the value of a Kendo ComboBox

Tags: hide, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I have a Kendo Grid in my application

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekResultaat>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
...
        columns.Bound(zoekResultaat => zoekResultaat.OpmerkingCode).ClientTemplate("#= OpmerkingCode#").Hidden(Model.DossierLijst);
        columns.Bound(zoekResultaat => zoekResultaat.OpmerkingOmschrijving).ClientTemplate("#= OpmerkingOmschrijving#").Hidden(Model.DossierLijst);
    })
   ...
    )
)
```

and a Kendo ComboBox

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(t => t.ZoekCriteria.Lijst)
                .Name("Lijst")
                .DataTextField("Omschrijving")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .Placeholder("Maak een selectie")
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "comboStyle" })
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action(MVC.Dashboard.ActionNames.LoadLijstIntoComboBox, MVC.Dashboard.Name);
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .AutoBind(false)
                .Value(Model.LijstDefault)
            )
```

Is it possible to hide one column based on the selected value of the ComboBox using Hidden()?

```
columns.Bound(zoekResultaat => zoekResultaat.OpmerkingOmschrijving).ClientTemplate("#= OpmerkingOmschrijving#").Hidden(**SelectedValueFromComboBox**);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columns.Bound(zoekResultaat => zoekResultaat.OpmerkingOmschrijving).ClientTemplate("#= OpmerkingOmschrijving#").Hidden(**SelectedValueFromComboBox**);
```

This is a server side action, can't depend on front-end operation(select combobox value).

You could use javascript to control the visiblility of column.

reference : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/